# ProbitModelFit is causing kernel crashes in Mathematica 12.0

Tags: fitting, crash

Mathematica 12.0

I am running `ProbitModelFit` on a small data set (~130 rows). Intermittently, the function causes a kernel crash. I am curious if anyone else is seeing this.

```
dm = 
 {{0.545924, 0.11973, 0.0436787, 0.119004, 0.171664}, {0.223581, 
  0.235577, 0.199634, 0.151053, 0.190156}, {0.105842, 0.441319, 
  0.0109707, 0.412198, 0.0296703}, {0.414089, 0.176884, 0.136009, 
  0.20624, 0.0667779}, {0.429945, 0.44826, 0.0242674, 0.0924908, 
  0.00503663}, {0.161326, 0.122065, 0.399815, 0.260825, 
  0.055969}, {0.28098, 0.352738, 0.0597344, 0.266758, 
  0.0397894}, {0.43022, 0.176099, 0.0597985, 0.240659, 
  0.0932234}, {0.127363, 0.38293, 0.0456777, 0.394982, 
  0.0490476}, {0.32117, 0.378305, 0.0267425, 0.171743, 
  0.102041}, {0.286493, 0.14881, 0.0659341, 0.0248168, 
  0.473947}, {0.253925, 0.389249, 0.053844, 0.210023, 
  0.0929596}, {0.175399, 0.272769, 0.37311, 0.126276, 
  0.0524464}, {0.153384, 0.197436, 0.379731, 0.133874, 
  0.135575}, {0.0732995, 0.339455, 0.0899267, 0.364909, 
  0.13241}, {0.0759715, 0.120897, 0.50879, 0.215952, 
  0.0783891}, {0.612485, 0.240385, 0.0323565, 0.0592186, 
  0.0555556}, {0.199734, 0.0970147, 0.490412, 0.110498, 
  0.102341}, {0.0721084, 0.00700966, 0.0657232, 0.0207237, 
  0.834435}, {0.0962302, 0.0292468, 0.0343025, 0.0580929, 
  0.782128}, {0.152822, 0.0551959, 0.625784, 0.0761128, 
  0.0900855}, {0.123276, 0.0262779, 0.575337, 0.0246953, 
  0.250414}, {0.0175824, 0.45641, 0.0445055, 0.424359, 
  0.0571429}, {0.319466, 0.106358, 0.0737834, 0.424647, 
  0.0757457}, {0.0874542, 0.207875, 0.0769231, 0.596154, 
  0.0315934}, {0.218681, 0.253297, 0.0403846, 0.379533, 
  0.108104}, {0.0379121, 0.146978, 0.279121, 0.380769, 
  0.15522}, {0.00549451, 0.265568, 0.223443, 0.503663, 
  0.0018315}, {0.270604, 0.385073, 0.0343407, 0.257326, 
  0.0526557}, {0.255952, 0.227106, 0.0242674, 0.0677656, 
  0.424908}, {0.0796703, 0.309982, 0.0325092, 0.19185, 
  0.385989}, {0.348901, 0.393773, 0.0581502, 0.186355, 
  0.0128205}, {0.447802, 0.346154, 0.00274725, 0.200549, 0.00274725}}

rm = 
  {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
   0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}

pm = ProbitModelFit[{dm, rm}]
```

The crash occurs when I execute the last line of code, but only sometimes.

Comment: Would you add a specific example?

Comment: Without reproducible code, there's very little anyone can do to help you.

Comment: Sorry, edited to include code.

Comment: On *Mathematica* 12.0.0.0 (Windows 10) running `ProbitModelFit` 2,000 times did not produce a crash:  `Do[pm = ProbitModelFit[{dm, rm}], {i, 2000}]`.  Maybe reboot?  reinstall *Mathematica*?

Comment: On Mathematica 12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) on the cloud I tried to run this a few thousand times in a Do loop like @JimB did and it never crashed either. Intermittent crashes are notoriously nasty to fix, sorry about that! Putting in a ticket with Wolfram support might be a better bet if the obvious restart etc do not fix it.

Comment: Why do you have to evaluate `pm = ProbitModelFit[{dm, rm}]` more than once?

Comment: I may evaluate more than once if:
1) I have to regenerate the input if I have not stored it.
2) generate new input.

Good question because I am not sure if it always fails for one particular data set or occasionally for one. Will need to pay attention and get back.

Thanks to everyone!